# Invalid volume specification trying to run portainer container

Tags: docker, windows-container, portainer

I'm trying to deploy portainer to my local docker. I'm running the Docker CE 18.0.6.0 version on Windows 10. I tried to follow the steps from these two pages:

1. [Portainer-Deployment](http://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html)
2. [Tutorial: Portainer for local Docker environments on Windows
   10!](https://lemariva.com/blog/2018/05/tutorial-portainer-for-local-docker-environments-on-windows-10)

But all the times I have tried to run the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer -H tcp://10.0.75.1:2375
```

Docker responds always with the same message:

> Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:
>   'portainer_data:/data'

I created the volume using this command:

```
docker volume create portainer_data
```

Any idea what could be?

Comment: Check your underscore, delete it and type it again by hand.

Comment: let me try that and I let you know the result

Comment: I removed the volume and create a new one without `_data` and the same result:`Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'portainer:/data'`

Comment: Those commands look right to me. This often means some other non-printable character got into the command.

Comment: I also went to the folder where I created the volume, I opened a console and I tried to run the command this time using `-v $(pwd):/data` but nothing. Do I need to specify the second part different, eg, C:\\data instead of /data?

Comment: I tried to use `mount` instead (`--mount source=portainer,target=/data`) and this time and this time this was the error:invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '/data'. That's why I think my error is in the target part

Comment: Are you running Linux containers?

Comment: No, windows containers. Do I need to switch?

Comment: There's the issue. Switch the engine back to Linux containers and it should work. Or you'll need a different syntax for Windows

Comment: OK, I did it and it worked this time but I'm curious how can be done in windows container.Do you know what changes I need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path syntax you used only works for Linux containers since Linux environments only have a single root to their filesystem tree. To run portainer container in a native Windows container, the syntax is:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine -v C:\ProgramData\Portainer:C:\data portainer/portainer
```

This comes from the [deployment documentation](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html).

Comment: Yes , what confused me was the second link I quoted in my question, thank you sir

Comment: @octavioccl You'll find that most documentation on docker containers is Linux focused. Windows containers are relatively new and I don't believe they've gotten all the same functionality working yet.